# In Windows 10 the file explorer does not remember its last window position. Can this be fixed?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

In Windows 10 the file explorer does not remember its last window position.

Can this be fixed?

Other programs remember their last position.

To reproduce:

1. Open file explorer
2. Move explorer window to the right
3. Close the window and reopen
4. Window opens on left side of the screen

EDIT: Here is some more discussion and possibly a hack to fix it:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-explorer-not-remembering-window-position/5db2e1e9-7c25-4808-8c36-837823ad972c

Comment: You should suggest this in the Windows Feedback App.

Comment: People have reported this broken since win7.  even in win 7 if you open 2 shortcuts for 2 different disks (same explorer program) only the last closed window will set the positioning for the next to open.  What is really wrong though is the position data for the seperate windows is still being stored into the registry Bags. It was demonstrated at microsoft community many times, some users were even treated to some deletion, because of bringing it up to often.

Comment: Doesn't it get stored even if you force to save the position using `CTRL + click on the close button` ?

Comment: @LPChip Nope...

Answer (score 1):

Version 10525 seems to remember the position for Explorer again, so Microsoft has fixed this.

Unfortunately there is no way to get the non-preview version to remember the position at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was removed by MS I think with windows 7, they did say so at the time. Personally I think it was a retrograde step, explorer windows opening in the same place is very annoying, especially if you want to copy/move from one to the other. While Linux window systems offer more functionality and user options with subsequent revisions MS seems to go the opposite way, forcing users to work in a ever increasingly fixed environment. If I do any serious work I do it in Linux where I can set up my environment to best suit the way I work, way more efficient. I find it extremely frustrating being forced to work the way MS think I should. Lets say you're working with a few programs opened, windows arranged and for some reason (new install, windows update) you need to reboot. Windows comes back up and all your programs and other windows are gone, you have to start over. Not so with Linux, all comes back the way you left it when you shut the computer down.